# MySQL query for aggregating terms over several conditions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Starting with data like the following:

```
clubType   desiredShape   lineDirection
---------------------------------------
driver     straight       left
driver     draw           straight
iron       straight       right
wedge      straight       straight
iron       fade           right
wedge      straight       straight
iron       fade           left
iron       draw           straight
```

I'd like to write a query that can return:

- count desiredShape = "draw"
- count desiredShape = "straight"
- count desiredShape = "fade"
- count lineDirection = "left"
- count lineDirection = "straight"
- count lineDirection = "right"

per each `clubType`

So, I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT
    clubType,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM shots WHERE desiredShape = "fade") as count_DesiredFade,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM shots WHERE desiredShape = "draw") as count_DesiredDraw,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM shots WHERE desiredShape = "straight") as count_DesiredStraight
    ...
FROM shots
GROUP BY clubType
```

But its not right. Not sure how to iterate over clubtype and aggregate the other counts, too.

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
clubType   desDraw   desFade   desStraight   lineLeft   lineRight   lineRight
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
driver     3         2         4             3          2           1
iron       4         1         2             4          2           1
wedge      1         3         2             1          0           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean expression to return a 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) or NULL. Wrap that in a `SUM()` aggregate, so you get a "count" of the rows where the boolean expression is TRUE.

For example:

```
SELECT t.clubType
     , SUM(t.desiredShape = 'fade') as count_DesiredFade
     , SUM(t.desiredShape = 'draw') as count_DesiredDraw
     , SUM(t.desiredShape = 'straight') as count_DesiredStraight
     , ...
  FROM shots t
 GROUP BY t.clubType
```

---

NOTE: The expression  `t.desired_shape = 'fade'` is equivalent to

```
  IF(t.desired_shape = 'fade',1,IF(t.desired_shape IS NULL,NULL,0))
```

or the more ANSI compliant

```
  CASE WHEN t.desired_shape = 'fade' 
         THEN 1
       WHEN t.desired_shape IS NULL
         THEN NULL
       ELSE 0
  END
```